# How to concat arrays using group keyword in pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a data in mongodb:

```
{'word': 'good', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 2}, {'tbl_id': 'd2', 'term_freq': 56}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 3}]}
{'word': 'spark', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 10}]}
{'word': 'good', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 12}, {'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 8}, {'tbl_id': 'd8', 'term_freq': 7}]}
{'word': 'spark', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd6', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd7', 'term_freq': 10}]}
```

and I want to reduce the same word, the info should be a integrated list. How to do it?

Expected output:

```
{'word': 'good',
 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 2}, {'tbl_id': 'd2', 'term_freq': 56}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 3},
          {'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 12}, {'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 8}, {'tbl_id': 'd8', 'term_freq': 7}]}
{'word': 'spark',
 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 10},
          {'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd6', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd7', 'term_freq': 10}]}
```

Comment: please add the expected output also

Comment: my expected output is:`{'word': 'good', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 2}, {'tbl_id': 'd2', 'term_freq': 56}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 3},{'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 12}, {'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 8}, {'tbl_id': 'd8', 'term_freq': 7}]}
{'word': 'spark', 'info': [{'tbl_id': 'd1', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd3', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd4', 'term_freq': 10}, {'tbl_id': 'd5', 'term_freq': 6}, {'tbl_id': 'd6', 'term_freq': 11}, {'tbl_id': 'd7', 'term_freq': 10}]}`

Comment: the same word should have only one `info`， and the element in the `info` should be integrated into one.

Comment: I have updated my answer, I think that will solve your case

Answer (score 2):

Below aggregate query will give you integrated info list, grouped by word

```
db.collection.aggregate([{'$unwind':'$info'},{'$group':{'_id':'$word','info':{'$push':'$info'}}}])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : "spark",
    "info" : [
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d1",
            "term_freq" : 6
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d3",
            "term_freq" : 11
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d4",
            "term_freq" : 10
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d5",
            "term_freq" : 6
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d6",
            "term_freq" : 11
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d7",
            "term_freq" : 10
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "good",
    "info" : [
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d1",
            "term_freq" : 2
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d2",
            "term_freq" : 56
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d3",
            "term_freq" : 3
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d4",
            "term_freq" : 12
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d5",
            "term_freq" : 8
        },
        {
            "tbl_id" : "d8",
            "term_freq" : 7
        }
    ]
}
```